# Understanding convergence in law to a continuous CDF

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of real random variables converging in law to $X$. Let us suppose that $F_{X}$ is continuous everywhere. If we have a sequence $\{a_n\}_n$ such that $F_{X_n}(a_{n})\rightarrow_{n}F_{X}(a) = 1/2$, could we assure that $a_n\rightarrow a$, knowing that $a$ is the unique point satisfying $F_{X}(a) = 1/2$? (i.e. $F^{-1}_{X}(1/2) = \{a\}$).

I reason by contradiction. Assume that $a_{n}\not\rightarrow a$, then, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|a_{n} - a| > \epsilon$ for every $n\geq N$, for a particular $N$. Then, we must show that there exists some $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|F_{X_n}(a_{n}) - F_{X}(a)| > \epsilon$ for every $n\geq M$, but I am stuck at this point.

Comment: What happens if $F_X(a)=F_X(b)$ for $b\neq a$?

Comment: You are right. I forgot some extra hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

First we recall that $F_{X_n}\to F_X$ uniformly. Hence,
$$
\begin{align}
|F_X(a)-F_X(a_n)|&\leq|F_X(a)-F_{X_n}(a_n)|+|F_{X_n}(a_n)-F_X(a_n)| \\
&\leq |F_X(a)-F_{X_n}(a_n)|+\lVert F_{X_n}-F_X \rVert_\infty \\
&\to0,
\end{align}
$$
where $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$ denotes the sup-norm.

Now, for any $\epsilon>0$ we must have that $F_X(a-\epsilon)<F_X(a)<F_X(a+\epsilon)$ since $F_X(x)=F_X(a)$ if and only if $x=a$. Then, by the convergence above, we must have that $F_X(a_n)\in(F_X(a-\epsilon),F_X(a+\epsilon))$ for all large enough $n$. Since $F_X$ is non-decreasing we have that $a_n\in(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ for all large enough $n$ which proves the convergence.